# GatewayFilter reactor mechanism

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm new to reactor and want to understand the difference between the below codes.

1. how are the two different? (rest of code given at the end)

```
// Version A
override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: GatewayFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
    return sample()
        .flatMap {
             val newRequest = exchange.request.mutate()
                .headers { httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.set("sample", it) }
                .build()
             chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(newRequest).build())
        }
        .onErrorResume(SampleException::class.java) { ex -> exchange.mutateToError() }
        .onErrorResume { exchange.mutateToError() }
}
```

vs

```
// Version B
override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: GatewayFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
    return sample()
        .onErrorResume(SampleException::class.java) { ex -> exchange.mutateToError() }
        .onErrorResume { exchange.mutateToError() }
        .flatMap {
            val newRequest = exchange.request.mutate()
                .headers { httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.set("sample", it) }
                .build()
            chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(newRequest).build())
        }
}
```

I understand that Version B doesn't work because the two `onErrorResume()`'s are returning `Mono<Void>`, while `sample()` returns `Mono<String>`. But apart from that, what I want to understand is, for Version A, the two `onErrorResume()`'s will trigger even when there are any kinds of error during the `chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(newRequest).build()` (ie. any errors in the proceeding chain). On the other hand, for Version B, the two `onErrorResume()`'s only trigger when there is an error during `sample()`. Is my understanding correct?

2. And if so, how would I go about correcting Version B, because my intent is to only "catch" from `sample()` and not from all proceeding chains as is in Version A. Version B requires a `Mono<String>` from the two `onErrorResume`s.

Relevant codes:

```
class SampleException : RuntimeException()
class SampleConfig
class SampleGatewayFilter(
    private val config: SampleConfig,
    private val webClient: WebClient,
) : GatewayFilter {
    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: GatewayFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        return sample()
            .flatMap {
                val newRequest = exchange.request.mutate()
                    .headers { httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.set("sample", it) }
                    .build()
                chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(newRequest).build())
            }
            .onErrorResume(SampleException::class.java) { ex -> exchange.mutateToError() }
            .onErrorResume { exchange.mutateToError() }
    }

    private fun ServerWebExchange.mutateToError(): Mono<Void> {
        val payload = """{"foo": "bar"}""".toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
        response.statusCode = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED
        response.headers.contentLength = payload.size.toLong()
        response.headers.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON

        val dataBuffer = response.bufferFactory().wrap(payload)
        return response.writeWith(Mono.just(dataBuffer))
    }

    private fun sample(): Mono<String> {
        return webClient.get()
            .uri("/api/v1/sample")
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus({ s -> s.is4xxClientError || s.is5xxServerError }, { Mono.empty() })
            .bodyToMono<CommonApiResponse<String>>()
            .onErrorResume { e ->
                logger.warn(e) { "Exception in sample" }
                Mono.error(e)
            }.flatMap {
                if (it.result == ResultType.SUCCESS) {
                    Mono.just(it.data)
                } else {
                    Mono.error(SampleException())
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `flatMapMany()` instead of chaining `onErrorResume()` and `flatMap()`.

```
// Version B
override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: GatewayFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
    return sample()
        .flatMapMany(
            {
                val newRequest = exchange.request.mutate()
                    .headers { httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.set("sample", it) }
                    .build()
                chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(newRequest).build())
            },
            { ex ->
                when (ex) {
                    is SampleException -> exchange.mutateToError()
                    else -> exchange.mutateToError()
                }
            },
            { Mono.empty() }
        ).next()
}
```

Had to use the `next()` as I can't find a way to insert a "nothing" instead of an "empty" into the flux for the onComplete. Otherwise, would've used `single()`.